# Django Url group only for Authenticated Users

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to crate Django web project , and there are some User backend application where every URL ( view ) only for authenticated users.
I can write a condition in every view for example:
**User/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^settings/', 'User.views.user_settings'),
   url(r'^profile/', 'User.views.profile'),
   #Other User Admin panel Urls
)
```

**User/views.py**

```
def user_settings(request):
    if request.user is None:
       return redirect('/login')
    #Some other code

def profile(request):
    if request.user is None:
       return redirect('/login')
    #Some other code
```

As you can see it's not well coded but it works fine.
The only thing that I want to know , is it possible to add some condition for **urls.py** file all urls for not adding same code lines in every view function.

For example Symfony , Laravel and Yii frameworks have something like that what I want to do.
**Is it possible do this in Django ? :)**

**Edited Here**

With `@login_required` I need to add it for every view, I need something for all urls for example: 
In Symfony framework I can write 
`{ path: ^/myPage, roles: AUTHENTICATED }` and every url like this `/myPage/someUrl` will be asked for authentication. 
I believe that Django have something like that :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you use a class based view, it makes easier for you to add @login_required. For example you can create a class based view here:

```
class BaseView(TemplateView):
   @method_decorator(login_required)
   def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(BaseView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now override it each time you want to create a new view. For example:

```
class SettingsView(BaseView):
     def get(request):
        return (...)
```

It will check each time at url dispatch if the user is logged in.

Also, if you use a class based view, you can override `get()` to check if the user is authenticated.

```
class BaseView(TemplateView):
   template_name= None
   role= None
   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.user is not None and role is "AUTHENTICATE":    
            return super(BaseView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise Exception('user is not logged in')
```

urls.py:

```
   url(r'^settings/', BaseView.as_view(template_name='/sometemplate', role="AUTHENTICATE")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@login_required` decorator:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator

From the docs:

> login_required() does the following:
>
> If the user isn’t logged in, redirect to settings.LOGIN_URL, passing the current absolute path in the query string. Example: /accounts/login/?next=/polls/3/.
>
> If the user is logged in, execute the view normally. The view code is free to assume the user is logged in.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def my_view(request):
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def my_view(request):
    ...
```